# How to attach data from local JS file to state in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am having trouble understanding how to access the data from a local JS file. I have read the React documentation up and down, but I'm stuck on this problem. There must be a flaw in my state/prop logic?

```
import announcementData from "./AnnouncementData.js"

class Detail extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      announcement: [
        {
          id: 0,
          ...
  }

  async fetchDetails(id) {
    let response = announcementData;
    this.state.announcement.map(response, (value, key) => {
      this.setState({
        [value]: key
      }).catch(error => {
        this.setState({
          error: error.message
        });
      });
    });
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const { match } = this.props;
    await this.fetchDetails(match.params.id);
  }

  render() {
    const detail = {
      id: this.state.announcement.id,
      title: this.state.announcement.title,
      site_id: this.state.announcement.site_id,
      content: this.state.announcement.content,
      status: this.state.announcement.status,
      scheduled_at: this.state.announcement.scheduled_at,
      created_at: this.state.announcement.created_at,
      categories: this.state.announcement.categories,
      members: this.state.announcement.members
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <ListGroup>
          <Announcement
            id={detail.id}
            title={detail.title}
            site_id={detail.site_id}
            content={detail.content}
            status={detail.status}
            scheduled_at={detail.scheduled_at}
            created_at={detail.created_at}
            categories={detail.categories}
            members={detail.members}
          />
        </ListGroup>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Announcement = ({id, title, site_id, content, status, scheduled_at, created_at, categories, members}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ListGroupItem>ID: {id}</ListGroupItem>
      <ListGroupItem>Title: {title}</ListGroupItem>
      <ListGroupItem>Site ID: {site_id}</ListGroupItem>
      <ListGroupItem>Content: {content}</ListGroupItem>
      <ListGroupItem>Status: {status}</ListGroupItem>
      <ListGroupItem>Scheduled at: {scheduled_at}</ListGroupItem>
      <ListGroupItem>Created at: {created_at}</ListGroupItem>
      <ListGroupItem>Categories: {categories}</ListGroupItem>
      <ListGroupItem>Members: {members}</ListGroupItem>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Detail;
```

I'm trying to publish the details from an array from a local file (for now) to be displayed by the UI. With this minimal code, I am able to display the "Announcement" function with no data, like so:

```
ID:
Title:
Site ID:
Content:
Status:
Scheduled at:
Created at:
Categories:
Members:
```

I need to display the actual data coming from the .js file.
It should be a very basic problem but I am a beginner. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

AnnouncementData.js:

```
const announcementData = [
  {
    id: 0,
    title: "John Doe",
    site_id: "my business",
    content: "I have a new business!",
    status: true,
    created_at: "14/03/2019",
    updated_at: "24/04/2019",
    categories: [{ id: 0, name: "John Doe" }],
    members: [{ id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", photo_url: "jane.png" }]
  },
export default announcementData;
```

Comment: what does `AnnouncementData.js` look like?

Comment: What are you exporting from `AnnouncementData.js` ?

Comment: `this.state.announcement.map(response, (value, key) => {....})` doesn't make sense, neither does `this.setState(....).catch`.

Comment: @Titus I added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change your `fetchDetails` function to something like this:

```
async fetchDetails(id) {
  this.setState({
    announcement: announcementData.find(v => v.id === id)
  }); 
}
```

Comment: I knew `fetchDetails` was a mess, this is much cleaner...however, same results (empty page)

Comment: @aaronalt `announcementData.find(v => v.id === id)` searches the array for an object that has the same `id` value as the `id` you pass to the `fetchDetails` function. I've used `===` which means that both values have to be the same type (both have to be strings or numbers, etc.).

Comment: Does it loop through the array? I think I need to attach each key in the array to a value in the component's state.

Comment: @aaronalt It just finds a value in the `announcementData` array and sets that as the state's `announcement` value. Arrays don't have keys, they have indexes. Looping the `announcementData` array doesn't make sense, it seems that you only need one of its values.

Comment: right, I need only one value from the array...how would I parse the data from that one value once it is set in state? (e.g. for title, site_id, content, etc.)

Comment: There is no need to parse anything, if you call `fetchDetails(0)` the component's state will be changed to `{announcement: {id: 0,
    title: "John Doe",
    site_id: "my business",
    content: "I have a new business!",
    status: true,
    created_at: "14/03/2019",
    updated_at: "24/04/2019",
    categories: [{ id: 0, name: "John Doe" }],
    members: [{ id: 1, name: "Jane Doe", photo_url: "jane.png" }]}}`

Comment: The only problem will be if you call `fetchDetails("0")` (zero as a string instead of a number), then, if all the `id`s in `announcementData` are numbers, no match will be found.

Comment: so how could I return each value in the state separately? inside the `componentDidMount` lifecycle after calling `await this.fetchDetails(match.params.id);`?

Comment: @aaronalt I'm not sure what you mean. Do you want to have multiple `Announcement` components ?

Comment: not components, but I need to list each value of the state (title, site_id, content, etc.) in an html page, based on it's id

Comment: @aaronalt It should do that, the problem is probably with `match.params.id`, try it using something like `await this.fetchDetails(0);` to see if it works.

Comment: Invariant Error: `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: @aaronalt That is probably because `members` is an array. You'll need to replace `<ListGroupItem>Members: {members}</ListGroupItem>`

Comment: ok now the content displays, but I need to: 1. make it so `members` and `categories` displays as well, 2. be able to fetch "id" without it being hard coded. Thanks for your help!